# WPF unity container fired singleton service twice

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, speechsynthesizer

Here is the program structure, App > Window > DataContext binding to MainViewModel

The MainViewModel contains 3 sub-ViewModel property, named as

- ViewModelA
- ViewModelB
- ViewModelC

each of sub-viewModel contains a dispatchertimer to get data from API and display on WPF.

I am going to inject a common voice service into all sub-viewModel, that will used by sub-viewModel to play voice.

The voiceService designed as singleton and allows sub-viewModel to add data, voiceService running a timer that watches on a List, play voice when new data arrived.

But I found the unity container fires the service twice, did my setting is incorrect

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
                VoiceService voiceService = new VoiceService();
                AutoMapperService autoMapperService = new AutoMapperService();
                this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(voiceService, autoMapperService);
                //this.DataContext = _container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>();
```

```
// app.xaml.cs
private void InitContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
            container.RegisterType<IVoiceService, VoiceService>();
            container.RegisterType<IAutoMapperService, AutoMapperService>();

            // for Unity 5, Unity has been broken down into a set of Packages for you to install only what you need.
            // If you need to do Registration By Convention -
            // which is what the RegisterTypes() method is used for,
            // you need to also install the NuGet Package,
            // Unity.RegistrationByConvention(version 2.1.0 as of this writing).

            // With Unity >=3, you can skip the container registration if you follow the naming convention like this:
            // This will register all types with a ISample/Sample naming convention 
            //container.RegisterTypes(
            //    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            //    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            //    WithName.Default);
        }
```

```
public class VoiceService : IVoiceService, IDisposable
    {
        protected readonly System.Timers.Timer announceTimer;
        protected readonly int defaultDataTimeInterval = 10;

        private List<VoiceAnnouncement> announcementQueueList = new List<VoiceAnnouncement>();
        private List<VoiceAnnouncement> announcedRecordList = new List<VoiceAnnouncement>();
        
        public VoiceAnnouncement currentAnnouncement = new VoiceAnnouncement();

        private SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        private volatile bool _isCurrentlySpeaking = false;

        /// <summary>Event handler. Fired when the SpeechSynthesizer object starts speaking asynchronously.</summary>
        private void StartedSpeaking(object sender, SpeakStartedEventArgs e)
        { this.GetInstance()._isCurrentlySpeaking = true; }
        /// <summary>Event handler. Fired when the SpeechSynthesizer object finishes speaking asynchronously.</summary>
        private void FinishedSpeaking(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
        { this.GetInstance()._isCurrentlySpeaking = false; }

        public event EventHandler OnSomeEvent = delegate { };
        public bool IsCurrentlySpeaking
        {
            get { return this._isCurrentlySpeaking; }
        }

        private static readonly Lazy<VoiceService> lazyAnnounceService = new Lazy<VoiceService>(() => new VoiceService());

        public VoiceService()
        {
            // don't use dispatchertime, use timer
            // otherwise the screen will freeze when speak
            this.announceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.defaultDataTimeInterval).TotalMilliseconds);
            this.announceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            announceTimer.Elapsed += PlayVoiceTimerTickTest;
            announceTimer.Start();

            //this.announceTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            //announceTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.defaultDataTimeInterval);
            //announceTimer.Tick += PlayVoiceTimerTick;
            //announceTimer.Start();

            this.speaker.SpeakStarted += new EventHandler<SpeakStartedEventArgs>(StartedSpeaking);
            this.speaker.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(FinishedSpeaking);
        }
        
        
        public VoiceService GetInstance()
        {
            return lazyAnnounceService.Value;
        }


        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            this.announceTimer.Elapsed -= this.PlayVoiceTimerTickTest;
            this.speaker.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: In your task that you start with `Task.Factory.StartNew` (you should use `Task.Run`) you have an `async` delegate, but now awaiting in the code block. Just a suggestion that you should change that. Only other suggestion is to read [ask].

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your information, I updated my founding on the post. I located the problem in the unity container which fires a service twice. Do you know how what happens?

Comment: Please don't clutter the title of the question with tags. The StackOverflow site is smart enough to prepend the most important tag to the title of the web page, to help the search engines catalog the page. There is no reason to do it yourself manually, and make your question less readable to humans for the (supposed) benefit of engines.